# Create a time aware flag to flag a user as new or active at a point of time

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a user table where id, date_last_login, and date_created are the relevant columns.

I want to create two measures and use them as filters. They should flag a user as active if they logged in within the last 30 days of the selected time range and as new if they registered within the last 15 days of the selected time range. I'm struggling to make it dynamic/time-aware.

The final result I want to achieve is a timeline or column chart showing the count of active users each day(or week, month, by connecting to date table with hierarchy) with the split of new/old users.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you have tried for these two measures.

Answer (score 0):

`dMin` and `dMax` are key here to get the date range from slicers, filters, or visual context (like chart axis).

`REMOVEFILTERS` is also important to remove the relationship from the Date table.

```
Active Users = 
  var dMin = MIN('Your Date Table'[Date])
  var dMax = MAX('Your Date Table'[Date])
  var result =
    CALCUALTE(
      DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK('DataTable'[UserId]),
      REMOVEFILTERS('Your Date Table'),
      'DataTable'[date_last_login] >= dMin - 30 &&
      'DataTable'[date_last_login] <= dMax
    )
  return result
```

```
New Users = 
  var dMin = MIN('Your Date Table'[Date])
  var dMax = MAX('Your Date Table'[Date])
  var result =
    CALCUALTE(
      DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK('DataTable'[UserId]),
      REMOVEFILTERS('Your Date Table'),
      'DataTable'[date_last_login] >= dMin - 15 &&
      'DataTable'[date_last_login] <= dMax
    )
  return result
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this doesn't meet the requirement unless I misunderstood. New User and Active User need to be boolean flags that I can use as legends on a graph, for example, a column chart with y being the count of the unique user ID and x being the date.

Comment: The above are Measures, after you create them, you can then drop both of these into your Chart Y-axis.

Comment: But I want to use them in the legend filed, to show the split between active users/inactive users. Not to use themselves as Y-axies.  They should be True/False. The code you provided returns a number. 

Is New User (Bool) = 
VAR CurrentDate = MAX('calendar'[Date])
VAR RegistrationCutoffDate = CurrentDate - 15
RETURN
MIN('v_user'[date_created_at]) > RegistrationCutoffDate &&
MIN('v_user'[date_created_at]) <= CurrentDate

I have tried this, but it doesn't work as a filter, nor can it be used in the legend field.

Comment: Best to share a sample PBIX (share a link, OneDrive, Google Drive, DropBox etc...). "Active vs Inactive"? `RegistrationCutoffDate` - these are all new things coming into the mix.

Comment: RegistrationCutoffDate was just the variable name. Inactive is just the opposite of active.  I can't really share PBIX, though; it's work-related. But thank you nonetheless :)

Comment: The two measure above in the answer are better than having a bool measure. You would use these measures in the Values of charts/visuals. You can add more than one measure in a chart Values well, and these then become the legend. Give it ago.

Comment: The problem is I want to use "New user" as a filter on another chart for Clicks per Product. I need to be able to toggle it to show either click per product for all users or click per product for only the new users.

Comment: With your help on the other question, I can now create separate pages for new users, existing users and all users. But it would be ideal if they could simply be a toggle.